# Building an efficient feature vector

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, feature-selection, accuracy

I am building a classifier for malware analysis, which predicts if I have a malware  by looking at the intructions of an assembly code, such as push, mov,... and predicting the optimization method. Note that I am considering a json file. My code is the following:

```
#pakages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json as j
import re
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import *
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from sklearn import svm

#for visualizing data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(font_scale=1.2)

%matplotlib inline

json_data = None;
with open('training_dataset.jsonl') as data_file:
    lines = data_file.readlines()
    joined_lines = "[" + ",".join(lines)+"]"

    json_data = j.loads(joined_lines)    

data = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
data.head()
```

[image]

```
myList = [];
for value in data['instructions'].iteritems():
    myList.extend(list(value[1]))

opcodes = [instruction.split()[0] for instruction in myList]
```

[image]

```
vect = CountVectorizer()
x = vect.fit_transform(opcodes)
a =vect.vocabulary_
```

[image]

```
X = list(a.values())
X_all = np.array(X).reshape(-1,1)



Y = list(data['opt'])
MlistY = Y[ :395]
y_all = np.array(MlistY)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_all, y_all, 
      test_size=0.2, random_state=15)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
model = SVC()

model.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

model.score(X_test,y_test)
```

so, what I did is doing a feature extraction where I counted the numner of times each instruction such as push,mov,... appearsin the training set, and use these numbers as feature vectors. After that I had to cut the column `data['opt']` in such a way to have the same number of elements of `X_all`. Then I split the dataset and I used as model support vector machines.

My problem is that the accuracy is very low, infact it is :  0.4810126582278481

I think this method I just used is called bag of words, but it is not very efficient for my case.

I think this is due to the fact that the method I used to extract the features is very inefficient.

My idea is to try to do a vectorization such that I assign to each operator a number, for example:

push -->0
mov -->1
jmp -->2
edx -->3

and so on and build a feature vector like this. But I also would like to keep track of the order on which the operators occurs inside the feature vector.

Is there a way to do this?

I have not found a specific vectorizer that does this, so is  there a way for doing this type of vectorization?

Thank's in advance.

[EDIT] To create such feature vector where I keep the order I tried the following:

```
opcodes_ordered = pd.factorize(opcodes)

opcodes_ordered_true = opcodes_ordered[0]

opcodes_ordered_true
```

which returns : `rray([ 0,  0,  0, ..., 22,  3,  5], dtype=int64)`

Now I create the feature vector and define a model:

```
X_all_2 = opcodes_ordered_true.reshape(-1,1)[:30000] #had to cut the vector 
                                                     #because y has 30000 
                                                     # elements

y_all_2 = list(data['opt'])

X_train_2, X_test_2, y_train_2, y_test_2 = train_test_split(X_all_2, 
y_all_2, test_size=0.2, random_state=15)

model_2 = SVC(kernel = 'sigmoid',gamma = 1.0)

model_2.fit(X_train_2,y_train_2)

y_pred_2 = model_2.predict(X_test_2)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test_2, y_pred_2))
print(classification_report(y_test_2, y_pred_2))

model_2.score(X_test_2,y_test_2)
```

but accuracy is still very low, in fact I have an accuracy of :

0.4841666666666667

I don't know what to do now.

[EDIT] I also tried to reduce the number of features, but by doing so I only got a small improvement.

[EDIT 2] What also I have tried to do is the following:

```
opcodes_ordered = pd.factorize(opcodes)

opcodes_ordered_true = opcodes_ordered[0]

opcodes_ordered_true
```

which gives as output : `array([ 0,  0,  0, ..., 22,  3,  5], dtype=int64)`

```
X_all_2 = opcodes_ordered_true.reshape(-1,1)[:1000]

y_all_2 = list(data['opt'])[:1000]

X_train_2, X_test_2, y_train_2, y_test_2 = train_test_split(X_all_2, 
y_all_2, test_size=0.2, random_state=15)

model_2 = SVC(kernel = 'linear',gamma = 1.0)

model_2.fit(X_train_2,y_train_2)

y_pred_2 = model_2.predict(X_test_2)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test_2, y_pred_2))
print(classification_report(y_test_2, y_pred_2))

model_2.score(X_test_2,y_test_2)
```

but I get as accuracy : 0.56

which is still low. Does anybdy know how could I have better accuracy? Thank's in advance.

[EDIT 3] I don't kow if I am doing it correctly but to see if the dataset is balanced or not, I looked how many times in a dataset I have optimization high (H) and optimizaion low (L), which is also what I would like to predict for new samples.

Sorry if I am not really precise but I just started with machine learning.

What I did is the following:

```
Y = list(data['opt'])

MlistY = Y

MlistY.count('L')
```

which returns : 17924

```
MlistY.count('H')
```

which returns: 12076

Moreover I have also tried to use TfidfVectorizer and what I did is:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=False, sublinear_tf=False,norm=None, 
analyzer='word') 

x = vectorizer.fit_transform(opcodes)

a = vectorizer.vocabulary_

X = list(a.values())

X_all = np.array(X).reshape(-1,1)

Y = list(data['opt'])[:395]

MlistY = Y

y_all = np.array(MlistY)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_all, y_all, 
test_size=0.3, random_state=15)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
model = SVC(kernel = 'linear',C= 1)

model.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

model.score(X_test,y_test)
```

and in this case the accuracy is : 0.5294117647058824

Moreover, if I print the classification report I find this:

[image]

in particular this is for the case of TfidfVectorizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J.D., welcome to Data Science Exchange.

First, let's start with the following question: Based on what target distribution are you saying that your accuracy is low? Every problem in modelling, Regression, Binary Classification, Multiclass Classification has a baseline so we can say that our model has an acceptable performance. Sometimes, even humans can be our baseline. Also, what is your dataset size?

Second, do you have a balanced dataset? What I mean is, after you calculate your baseline, you might have a class, let's say no malware code that dominates your dataset. You should assign this by using method for imbalanced datasets such as Oversampling and Undersampling. You can read more about [here](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auto_examples/index.html).

Lastly, let's ignore everything I wrote and focus on the problem. Yes, you are correct, Bag of Words will ignore order in your data since it will just count the appearance of each word. I will list a few things you can try:

- You are using SVC class from sklearn. From docs I see the default kernel is rbf, have you tried using linear? Also, you can use LinearSVC.
- Try out RandomForest models, they perform really good even in text datasets.
- From CountVectorizer class, you could vary ngram_range parameters. Basically, it will create features based on grams, so let's say you use a 3-gram approach, then you will have for your first row: push_r12_push_rbp counting as one feature.
- Also, you could try [Tf-Idf Vectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html). TF-IDF Vectorizer is based on an algorithm where not only the count of words is taken into account but also the appearance in each document. Putting in simple terms, if a specific word appears too much in your dataset it will have a high inverse value and decrease its feature value, since this word will not be useful to differentiate your class.
  You can read more about it here: https://www.quora.com/How-does-TF-IDF-work
- Lastly, but not less important, you could try using a more advanced technique, WordEmbeddings, for example. It is an algorithm that will create real vectors from your text taking in consideration the enclosing words for each command. It is a little more complicate than that, again, you can learn more [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-word-embedding-and-word2vec-652d0c2060fa).
  Note that for word embeddings to work properly, you should not have a small dataset. As a code example you can use this [notebook of mine as a guidance](https://github.com/vtoliveira/advanced-data-science-capstone/blob/master/Feature%20Creation%20(Word%20Embeddings)%20-%20Twitter%20US%20Airline%20Sentiment.ipynb).

I hope this help.

Comment: thank you it was really helful. I have some improvements, but still the maximum I can reach is 0.56 of accuracy. By using random forests I got 0.55 so better then before. My objective is to reach at least 0.7 or ideally also 0.8 or 0.9, but I am trying and trying but I don' t get a solution. Maybe a good idea would be to build a feature vector that keeps the order of the operation as they are performed, but don't know how to do it. Can I ask you if you have any idea on how to do this? Thank's in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using Tf-IDf Vectorizer? Also, can you tell us how is your datataset's balance? That is, the number of instances for each class in Y vector.

Comment: Thank you again for the answer, I have edited the post.